# Eclipse syntax coloring for C / C++ comments

Tags: colors, eclipse, syntax-highlighting

When writing C/C++ code in eclipse, is it possible to set up the syntax colouring in such a way that it displays comments starting with `/**` in another colour than normal multi-line comments (starting only with `/*`)?

What I want to acheive is basically a javadoc-style colouring for comments attached to methods/classes.

Comment: I think you'd be better asking this question over at Stackoverflow, as I'd think this question would qualify as a programming question.

Comment: @PaulHay A question about changing the options of a program on Stack Overflow is going to get booted back to Super User pretty quickly...

Comment: I suppose, but the question's more likely to find someone who's already solved this question for their own needs on stackoverflow.

Comment: Have you looked under [Syntax Coloring preferences](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_c_editor_color.htm) to see how Comment colours can be customised?

Comment: @Karan I have, you can set appearance individually for single- and multi-line comments, which are coloured regardless of the number of asterisks on the first line.